# ngrok in docker cannot connect to Django development server

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose, ngrok

I am working on a localhost django webserver `http://localhost:8000`, which works fine.
Meanwhile i need ngrok to do the port forwarding, `ngrok http 8000`, which works fine too.

Then I want to put ngrok, postgres, redis, maildev, etc all in docker containers, all others works fine, except ngrok.

ngrok failed to contain to localhost:8000.

I understand why, i suppose because ngrok is running on a seperate 'server 'and the localhost on that server does not have web server running.

I am wondering how i can fix it.

- I tried in my docker-compose file with
  `network_mode: "host"`, it is not working (MacOS).
- I tried to use host.docker.internal, but as I am a free plan user, ngrok does not allow me to specify a hostname.

any help is appreciated! Thanks.

here is my docker-compose file:

```
    ngrok:
        image: wernight/ngrok
        ports:
            - '4040:4040'
        environment:
            - NGROK_PORT=8000
            - NGROK_AUTH=${NGROK_AUTH_TOKEN}
        network_mode: "host"
```

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE:

stripe has a new tool `[stripe-cli][1]`, which can do the same thing.
just do as below

```
stripe-cli:
      image: stripe/stripe-cli
      command: listen --api-key $STRIPE_SECRET_KEY
                    --load-from-webhooks-api
                    --forward-to host.docker.internal:8000/api/webhook/
```

---

I ended up getting rid of ngrok, using serveo instead to solve the problem,
here is the code, in case anyone run into the same problem

```
serveo:
    image: taichunmin/serveo
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    command: "ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=60 -R 80:host.docker.internal:8000 -o \"StrictHostKeyChecking no\" serveo.net"
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it to work by doing the following:

1. Instruct Django to bind to port 8000 with the following command: `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`
2. Instruct ngrok to connect to the `web` docker service in my docker compose file by passing in `web:8000` as the `NGROK_PORT` environment variable.

I've pasted truncated versions of my settings below.

*docker-compose.yml*:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  ngrok:
    image: wernight/ngrok
    depends_on:
      - web
    env_file:
      - ./ngrok/.env
    ports:
      - 4040:4040

  web:
    build:
      context: ./app
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    env_file:
      - ./app/django-project/settings/.env
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - ./app/:/app/
```

And here is the env file referenced above (i.e. `./ngrok/.env`):

```
NGROK_AUTH=your-auth-token-here
NGROK_DEBUG=1
NGROK_PORT=web:8000
NGROK_SUBDOMAIN=(optional)-your-subdomain-here
```

You can leave out the subdomain and auth fields. I figured this out by looking through their [docker entrypoint](https://github.com/wernight/docker-ngrok/blob/master/entrypoint.sh)